# Optimizing stack memory read/writes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, stack, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

Let's say we have the following function with a loop that writes some memory variable within each iteration of the loop.

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let myStackVariable = i;
    // do something with myStackVariable
  }
}
```

But let's say we re-write this loop to declare the variable only once outside of the loop and then re-assign it during the loop.

```
function myFunction() {
  let myStackVariable;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    myStackVariable = i;
    // do something with myStackVariable
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that in any decent `C` compiler will optimize only a single variable in the stack and consistently use that memory location.

Will JavaScript likely do the same? Is there any benefit performance wise to doing the latter? Is it worth writing one way rather than the other. I know, I know - premature optimization is the root of all evil - but I am more curious than anything.

I tried running tests with `n = 100000000` and the results were the same, but I'm unsure if my example was just too simple since there are no recursions, etc.

Comment: If you ran it with that many iterations and there was no difference, I think you have the answer to "Is there any benefit performance wise to doing the latter?" As far as "Will JavaScript likely do the same?" I don't believe there's anything in the specification about that kind of optimization. Therefore, it will be up to each implementation whether they do it or not. Do you have a specific engine in mind?